# how to export data from hortonworks hive to cassandra?

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hive, cassandra-2.0, datastax

I want to export data from hortonworks hive to Cassandra
Is there a way to export data from Horton works Hive to datastax Cassandra without using ETL tools?

Comment: Use spark-submit command => spark-submit --class <java_class_with_export_logic> --master local --deploy-mode client --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/absolute-path/<driver-jar> --jars /absolute-path/<driver-jar> /absolute-path/<application-jar <JDBC_URL>

Answer (score 0):

You use Sqoop for this.

> Apache Sqoop
>
> Apache Sqoop(TM) is a tool designed for efficiently transferring bulk
>   data between Apache Hadoop and structured datastores such as
>   relational databases.
>
> Sqoop successfully graduated from the Incubator in March of 2012 and
>   is now a Top-Level Apache project.

[interwebs link](http://sqoop.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Using Apache Spark with the Spark-Cassandra connector and saveToCassandra is another choice and one I see recommended more these days over Sqoop. You can use Spark as a basic load tool, or you can use it to also perform ETL transformations on your data.